# mkdocs: How to create Folder like structure

Tags: web, directory, mkdocs

I want to create a small local file with my personal lecture notes. The Structure that I want is

Index 1 (contains overview of subfolders, but not the full content of them)
    Index 1.1 (contains overview of subfolders but not the full content of them)
        Index 1.1.1 (contains content of section)

At the moment my mkdocs.yml looks like

```
site_name: Lectures

theme: readthedocs

extra_javascript: 
    - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML

markdown_extensions:
    - mdx_math

pages:
- Lecture1 
  - 'week 1': 'lec1/week1.md'
      - 'section 1': 'lec1/week1/sec1.md
```

But the previous code does not display it like I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `pages` config is not valid.

First, a section must end in a colon (`:`) to indicate that the indented lines which follow are children of the section.

```
- Lecture:
  - 'week 1'...
```

Second, only a "section" can have children. A "page" cannot have children.

```
- 'week 1':
  - Summary: 'lec1/week1.md'
  - 'section 1': 'lec1/week1/sec1.md'
```

Yes, that means you need to add an extra entry for the `week1.md` page. I gave it the title `Summary`. Of course, you could use whatever name you think is more appropriate. In any event, the full config should look like this:

```
pages:
  - Lecture:
    - 'week 1':
      - Summary: 'lec1/week1.md'
      - 'section 1': 'lec1/week1/sec1.md'
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your quick answer! I will accept the answer as soon as I have time to try your solution.

Comment: How can I use German umlauts in the mkdocs.yml file? I already tried to use HTML codes but the page does not refresh if I use them.

Comment: Hmm ... are there other ways to create Folder like structures? It does seem very redundant when using this method.

Comment: An attempt was made at providing an alternate [here](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1042), but there are a number of unresolved issues so it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will have to figure out a way how I can do this.